# Windows AppFabric Server (win2k8) not working with distributed cache client on win2k3

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, appfabric

We have windows appfabric cache server on win2k8 server and have installed “Windows Server 2003 Distributed Cache Client” on win2k3 web server from [this link](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=d1ca30df-0e84-4388-8636-2ef87380600c&displaylang=en) .

We are getting below exception while getting the cache object from cache factory.Can anybody help us to understand the cause of exception and its solution? Please note that below exception is not thrown while adding or getting cache data.

Our main purpose is to get & put cache data to windows appfabric server(win2k8) from win2k3 webserver client.

Exception:-

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: There was an error deserializing the object . Input string was not in a correct format. ---> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToInt32(IFormatProvider provider)
at System.Convert.ToInt32(Object value, IFormatProvider provider)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterConverter.ToInt32(Object value)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo.GetInt32(String name)
at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.EvictionConfig..ctor(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
at ReadEvictionConfigFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString[] , XmlDictionaryString[] )
at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.ReadDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlReaderDelegator reader)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserializeInSharedTypeMode(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 declaredTypeID, Type declaredType, String name, String ns)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Type declaredType, String name, String ns)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.ReadSerializationInfo(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Type type)
at ReadPolicyConfigFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString[] , XmlDictionaryString[] )
at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.ReadDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlReaderDelegator reader)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserializeInSharedTypeMode(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 declaredTypeID, Type declaredType, String name, String ns)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Type declaredType, String name, String ns)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.ReadSerializationInfo(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Type type)
at ReadNamedCacheConfigurationFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString[] , XmlDictionaryString[] )
at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.ReadDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlReaderDelegator reader)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserializeInSharedTypeMode(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 declaredTypeID, Type declaredType, String name, String ns)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Type declaredType, String name, String ns)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.NetDataContractSerializer.InternalReadObject(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Boolean verifyObjectName)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator reader, Boolean verifyObjectName)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator reader, Boolean verifyObjectName)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader reader)
at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Utility.Deserialize(Byte[][] buffers, Boolean checkTypeToLoad)
at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.RoutingClient.GetCacheProperties()
at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheFactory.GetCache(String cacheName)
```

Comment: Can you give us anything more to go on that just a stack trace? Some source code perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code snippet :-

```
DataCacheFactoryConfiguration configuration = new DataCacheFactoryConfiguration();
List<DataCacheServerEndpoint> servers = new List<DataCacheServerEndpoint>(1);
servers.Add(new DataCacheServerEndpoint("localhost", 22233));
configuration.Servers = servers;
DataCacheSecurity security = new DataCacheSecurity(DataCacheSecurityMode.None, DataCacheProtectionLevel.None);
configuration.SecurityProperties = security;
DataCacheFactory factory = new DataCacheFactory(configuration);
DataCache cache = factory.GetCache("default"); // above exception is thrown here
```